# MySQL query error - can't figure out what it might be?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$sql = 'SELECT track_id, track_title, track_num, al.album_name, g.genre_name, a.artist_name, length, track_rating '.
        'FROM album x, genre g, artist a, album al '.
        'WHERE x.genre = g.genre_id AND x.artist = a.artist_id AND x.album = al.album_id';
```

Error I get: Unknown column 'track_id' in 'field list'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output from `describe <table>` for all the tables involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to qualify the column names.

```
$sql = 'SELECT x.track_id, x.track_title, x.track_num, al.album_name,...
```

Since you are referencing more than one table, MySQL doesn't know which table the column `track_id` would exist in. Explicitly specifying `x.track_id` tells it the column is in the table aliased `x`, in this case, `album`.

Also, why are you referencing the table `album` twice?

`'FROM album x, genre g, artist a, album al '.`

Comment: Didn't help - Unknown column 'x.track_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Does a column `track_id` exist in the table `album`? Check for spelling discrepancies.

Comment: Surely if that column existed in more than one table, it would complain about an ambiguous column rather than a missing one?

Comment: I suppose that's true. I believe the issue might be he's referencing the table `album` twice, with different aliases each time.

Answer (score 1):

The error might be that you forgot to include a table.

the answer from xbonez, that it does not know from which table to use `track_id` does not apply in this case, then you would have got another error like `Column 'track_id' in field list is ambiguous ...`

You might need `FROM album x, genre g, artist a, track t ..`